# Looking for a concise SQL statement to achieve the functionality

Tags: sql, oracle

I have wrote a complex query to implement this requirement, i wonder is there a better way to do that.

Requirement:
Choose the rows by the condtions below

1. end_month = max(working_month)
   OR
2. end_month >= current month

Remove the duplicate rows from the result above

[image]

Comment: SO is not a free coding service. We're more than happy to help once you've made an effort to solve the problem yourself and run into difficulties. When that happens, you can explain the issue you've encountered, include the relevant portions of your code along with your schema (CREATE TABLEs), sample data (INSERTs), the output you want to obtain from that data, and the SQL you've written, and ask a specific qeustion related to that SQL, and we can try to help. See [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055).

Comment: We cannot tell you whether there is a "better" way, because you have not shown your query. Show your query, so we might be able to point out whether this or that method might be better in our opinion.

Answer (score 2):

It is unclear what should be considered as current month - is it sysdate month or working month.
Anyway, you should convert string dates to date datatype to do comparisons. Use Max() Over() analytic function to get max working month per worker id...

```sql
WITH    --  S a m p l e    D a t a :
    tbl (WORKER_ID, WORKING_MONTH, START_MONTH, END_MONTH) AS
        ( Select 'A1', '2023/12', '2023/09', '2023/11' From Dual Union All
          Select 'A1', '2023/11', '2023/09', '2023/11' From Dual Union All
          Select 'A1', '2023/10', '2023/09', '2023/11' From Dual Union All
          Select 'A1', '2023/09', '2023/09', '2023/11' From Dual Union All
          Select 'A2', '2023/11', '2023/09', '2023/11' From Dual Union All
          Select 'A2', '2023/10', '2023/09', '2023/11' From Dual Union All
          Select 'A2', '2023/09', '2023/09', '2023/11' From Dual Union All
          Select 'A3', '2023/10', '2023/09', '2023/11' From Dual 
        )
```

```sql
--  M a i n    S Q L :
SELECT  WORKER_ID, WORKING_MONTH, START_MONTH, END_MONTH
FROM    ( Select  t.*, 
                  Max(To_Date(t.WORKING_MONTH, 'yyyy/mm')) Over(Partition By t.WORKER_ID) "MAX_WRK_MTH",
                  To_Date(t.WORKING_MONTH, 'yyyy/mm') "WRK_MTH",  -- if current month is working month
                  To_Date(t.END_MONTH, 'yyyy/mm') "END_MTH",
                  Trunc(SYSDATE, 'mm') "SYS_MTH"    -- if current month is SYSDATE month
          From    tbl t 
        )
WHERE   END_MTH = MAX_WRK_MTH
        OR
        END_MTH >= WRK_MTH
```

```sql
/*    R e s u l t :   (if current month is working month)
WORKER_ID  WORKING_MONTH  START_MONTH  END_MONTH
---------  -------------  -----------  ---------
A1         2023/11        2023/09      2023/11
A1         2023/10        2023/09      2023/11
A1         2023/09        2023/09      2023/11
A2         2023/11        2023/09      2023/11
A2         2023/10        2023/09      2023/11
A2         2023/09        2023/09      2023/11
A3         2023/10        2023/09      2023/11    */
```

... if current month is sysdate month - change the last condition in where clause - the result would be different

```sql
OR
END_MTH >= SYS_MTH
```

```sql
/*    R e s u l t :   (if current month is sysdate month)
WORKER_ID  WORKING_MONTH  START_MONTH  END_MONTH
---------  -------------  -----------  ---------
A2         2023/11        2023/09      2023/11
A2         2023/10        2023/09      2023/11
A2         2023/09        2023/09      2023/11
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the maximum working month using `MAX(working_month) OVER ()` (or `MAX(working_month) OVER (PARTITION BY something_you_did_not_mention)` if you want the maximum for each partition) and you can get the current month using `TRUNC(SYSDATE)` or `TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'YYYY/MM')` then you just need to compare those to `end_month`:

```sql
SELECT worker_id,
       working_month,
       start_month,
       end_month
FROM   (
  SELECT worker_id,
         working_month,
         start_month,
         end_month,
         MAX(working_month) OVER () AS max_working_month
  FROM   table_name
)
WHERE  end_month =  max_working_month
OR     end_month >= TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'YYYY/MM')
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (WORKER_ID, WORKING_MONTH, START_MONTH, END_MONTH) AS
  SELECT 'A1', '2023/12', '2023/09', '2023/11' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'A1', '2023/11', '2023/09', '2023/11' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'A1', '2023/10', '2023/09', '2023/11' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'A1', '2023/09', '2023/09', '2023/11' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'A2', '2023/11', '2023/09', '2023/11' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'A2', '2023/10', '2023/09', '2023/11' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'A2', '2023/09', '2023/09', '2023/11' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'A3', '2023/10', '2023/09', '2023/11' FROM DUAL;
```

Which outputs zero rows since: the maximum working date is `2023/12` and none of the end months matches that value and `SYSDATE` is currently `2024/01` and none of the end months are greater or equal to it.

If you want to use `PARTITION BY worker_id` when finding the maximum then the output would be:

| WORKER_ID | WORKING_MONTH | START_MONTH | END_MONTH |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A2 | 2023/11 | 2023/09 | 2023/11 |
| A2 | 2023/10 | 2023/09 | 2023/11 |
| A2 | 2023/09 | 2023/09 | 2023/11 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/PXm_fTav)

Comment: @dr If you feel it is too similar then I can delete this; however I'd approached this looking at current month being `SYSDATE` and the OP's string format is almost ISO8601 format so no need to convert to a `DATE` for comparison. I'd not spotted your addendum about `SYSDATE` otherwise I might not have written my answer. (I also think you may overestimate how much I use the downvote button - I tend to reserve that for when answers are unfixably wrong and comment when an answer is mostly correct but has edge cases when it won't work but could be fixed; others may DV based on that comment though).